# IF statement on insert using 'with'

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic, conditional-statements

I have the following query:

```
;WITH tbldata as (
SELECT a, b FROM Some_Table
)
INSERT INTO Target_Table(column1, column2)
SELECT a,b FROM tbldata
```

I would like to make the insert conditional:

```
;WITH tbldata as (
SELECT a, b FROM Some_Table
)
IF @insert = 1
INSERT INTO Target_Table(column1, column2) SELECT a,b FROM tbldata
ELSE
SELECT a,b FROM tbldata
```

but I get an error stating: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.`

How would I solve this? I have been thinking about s'thing along the lines

```
;WITH tbldata as (
SELECT a, b FROM Some_Table
)
INSERT INTO TEMP_Table(column1, column2) SELECT a,b FROM tbldata 

--effectively dumping it in a temptable before deciding whether to insert or view it

IF @insert = 1
INSERT INTO Target_Table(column1, column2) SELECT a,b FROM TEMP_Table 
ELSE
SELECT a,b FROM tbldata
```

but somehow that looks 'dirty' to me. Suggestions? Or am I overseeing s'thing?

I am eager to hear your suggestions!

Comment: your error is because of this: A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: I ended up using a in-memory temptable. Dirty but does the trick. Thanks for clarifying this for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need are locally defined views. Unfortunately SQL Server does not have them. A CTE can only belong to one query, it cannot be shared. This means that you must do one of the following:

1. Duplicate the CTE to both branches of the IF
2. Define a view
3. Define a table-valued function
4. Copy the contents of the CTE into a temp table or table variable to avoid duplication

Comment: I dump the contents in a temptable and based on the condition insert them from the temptable into the final table (or not ;p)

Comment: I ended up using a in-memory temptable. Dirty but does the trick. Thanks for clarifying this for me!.